# How Can I use the system call write() to output to a file (write to a file)?

Tags: c++, c, file-io, operating-system, system-calls

So I am learning an operating systems course and right now I am learning how to do system calls. So Basically ,I want to copy an input file openClose.in to a file called openClose.out. So far here is my code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/types.h> //needed for open
#include <sys/stat.h>  //needed for open
#include <fcntl.h>     //needed for open
#include <errno.h>      //must use for perror
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>


using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    int inFile;
int outFile;
    int n_char=0;
char buffer[32];
int fstat(int fildes, struct stat *buf);
struct stat statBuf;
struct group grp;
struct passwd pwd;

int err;
int err2;


    if(argc != 3) 
    { 
    printf("Usage: openClose <infile> <outfile> \n");
    //return 1;
    exit(1);
}


    inFile=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
outFile=open(argv[2],O_RDWR);
    if (inFile==-1)
    {
       printf("");
       perror(argv[1]);
       exit(1);

    }

    //Use the read system call to obtain 32 characters from inFile
    while( (n_char=read(inFile, buffer, 32))!=0)
    {
            //Display the characters read
            n_char=write(argv[2],buffer,n_char);
    }

err = fstat(inFile, &statBuf);
printf("The is the status of %d\n", argv[1]);
printf("File Size \t Owner \t Group ID \t Last Modified \n %d \t \t %d \t %d \t \t %d \n",statBuf.st_size,statBuf.st_uid,stat,statBuf.st_gid,statBuf.st_mtime);


    return 0;
 }
```

But I couldn't seem to get it working, for some reason, I don't know why I am not able to see the output file.

I am running my program from the terminal with two arguments like the following

open(executable) inputfile1 inputfile2

Comment: You open 'outFile', but try to write to 'argv[2]'.  That's not gonna work!

Comment: ...thats assuming that outFIle got opened OK - you must check the result of ALL system calls.

Comment: ..and close files when done to flush them and clean up fd's.

Comment: @MartinJames so what should I use instead of argv[2], should I use outFile it self.

And when closing, should I just say close(inFile); close(outFile) ??

Comment: @Pro Please don't update the code in your question to reflect the changes suggested in answers — it makes the question not make any sense, because the code is now correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) is not correct:

```
        n_char=write(argv[2],buffer,n_char);
```

The first argument should be a file descriptor, so use `outFile` instead of the file name in `argv[2]`.

By the way, you should take the habit of verifying if your opening succeded, before trying to do any file i/o.  You did it well for `inFile`, do it also for `outFile`

Comment: I fixed this but still couldn't find my file !

One more thing, I want to display the name of the output file argv[2].

How would I do this ??

so I want to print the status of the outputfile
printf("The is the status of %d\n", argv[2]);

This prints me a number not a filename ?

Comment: For the printing, replace %d with %s (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf) for the formatting chars in printf() or switch to the c++ streams).

Comment: Please check the result from the opening of your outFile, to make sure it succeded (or to get error message if it doesn't)

Comment: ok actually when I tried to do verification for the output file , it told me not such file or directory ? Why didn't it just create the outputfile given when running the program ? Why should I create it before running the program ?

Comment: I edited my code with checking the outFile and it tells me no such file or directory ?

Comment: My question is now basically, How can you create the file if it doesn't exist with write() ?

Comment: I figured it out I just need to add | o_create with the open system call

Comment: Look up the man page for open() and check out the required flags